# Binding Ipywidgets value to a variable

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I am using ipywidgets to take user inputs in Jupyter Notebook. Below, I put the code for most two frequent types I am using:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

widgets.BoundedIntText(
    min=0,
    max=90,
    step=1,
    description='Surface Tilt (in °)',
    disabled=False
)

widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=['South', 'East-West'],
    description='Orientation',
    disabled=False
)
```

However, I can't figure out from the documentation, how can I save the user input to a variable so I can use it next cells.

Any help or alternative solutions/packages to facilitate will be appreciated.

Best,

Debayan

Comment: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Basics.html#Widget-properties This part of the docs shows how you can access the widget value. You need to assign a variable name to the widget itself first.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to assign a name to each widget, [as @ac24 mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69785594/binding-ipywidgets-value-to-a-variable/72633126#comment123369388_69785594). Then by using the `value` property you can get the value for each widget.

By running the code below you can print the values for both of your widgets:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

BoundedIntText_widget = widgets.BoundedIntText(
    min=0,
    max=90,
    step=1,
    description='Surface Tilt (in °)',
    disabled=False
)

RadioButtons_widget = widgets.RadioButtons(
    options=['South', 'East-West'],
    description='Orientation',
    disabled=False
)

print(BoundedIntText_widget.value , RadioButtons_widget.value)
```